# Why JSON show no data

Tags: php, arrays, json

Error when using `some.php?id=$id`

I have table named `tb_syarat_layanan`.   When I try to get JSON, array it shows no Data.

```
<?php

 //Importing database
 require_once('koneksi.php');

 $query = "select * from tb_syarat_layanan WHERE id_layan=$id";
 $hasil = mysqli_query($con,$query);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($hasil) > 0 )
 {
     $response = array();
     $response["data"] = array();
     while($x = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil)) 
     {
         $h['id_layan'] = $x["id_layan"];     
         $h['dokumen'] = $x["dokumen"];
         array_push($response["data"], $h);
     }
     echo json_encode($response);
 }
 else 
 {
     $response["message"] = "No Data";
     echo json_encode($response);
 }

?>
```

But when I set my $query like this :

```
$query = "select * from tb_syarat_layanan WHERE id_layan=1";
```

it show the data that I want

JSON shows no data when $query is set with variable `$id`

Comment: It appears that `$id` are not being (or being wrongly) set. Could you post the code where you set that variable?

Comment: Right after the `$query = ...` line, put `print($query);` and post the result here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you are getting the id from the URL. Data sent on query string are stored inside [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php)

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_syarat_layanan WHERE id_layan = $id";
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have some.php?id=1 in the URL. You need a way to get that id parameter from the query string. In PHP, this can be done easily using the `$_GET` superglobal. `$_GET` allows you to access the values passed in the query string.

So in your code, you can do something like:

```
  $id = $_GET['id'];
```

The best practice is to escape any input passed in the query string:

```
 $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
```

But if you aren't outputting that input anywhere in the page where it can be executed, and you aren't storing the query parameters for output later, this shouldn't be a problem. The only real danger here would be SQL injection. The best method for avoiding this would be to use prepared statements. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: $id = $_GET['id']; is a solution for me

Comment: That's fine, but just be careful using that code in the wild. It would be easy for an attacker to pass a malicious SQL in your query string. That's why I recommended you use prepared statements.